# Angles in the Capstan (Eytelwein's) Equation

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics

I'm trying to derive the Capstan formula as described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capstan_equation

If you take a look at the diagram:

[image]

**How do you know both of those angles are equal?**  I imagine the rope goes through a circular section of angle theta, but cannot understand why the the angle of T_load with respect to the X axis is also theta.

Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 2):

Because the rope "leaves" the capstan on the right hand side of the diagram at a tangent to the capstan's surface. Thus the angle between the rope and the radial line where it leaves is a right angle.

One is assuming a thin, highly bendable rope.

Comment: And what goes unsaid in your answer (perhaps rightly!) is that it's then a matter of simple high-school geometry to see that both angles must be equal.